# Using jQuery how do I get window height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've tried to use jQuery to get the window height/width in the `onload()` method of an HTML page however it just throws an exception. I'm obviously doing something wrong as I'm a beginner with HTML5, Javascript and jQuery.

HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Testing Javascript Raphael</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/raphael/raphael-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/our_script.js" ></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="canvas_container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript `our_script.js`:

```
//var paper = new Raphael(10, 50, 320, 200);
//var circle = paper.circle(50, 40, 10);
//circle.attr("fill", "#f00");
//circle.attr("stroke","#fff");

window.onload = function() {  
//var paper = new Raphael(document.getElementById('canvas_container'), $( window ).width(), $( height).height());
var height = $( window ).height(); // ** This call does not work - exception is thrown and height variable remains undefined.
//var paper = new Raphael(document.getElementById('canvas_container'), 500,500);  
//var circle = paper.circle(100, 100, 80);  
//for(var i = 0; i < 5; i+=1) {  
    //var multiplier = i*5;  
    //paper.circle(250 + (2*multiplier), 100 + multiplier, 50 - multiplier)  
//}  
//var rectangle = paper.rect(200, 200, 250, 100);  
//var ellipse = paper.ellipse(200, 400, 100, 50);  
};

window.onresize = function() {
  var r = $( window ).height();
  var w = $( window ).width();
};

$( window ).load( function() {
  var height = $( window ).height();
  var width = $( window ).width();
});
```

Am I unable to query the window object for height/width in the onload call?

Comment: Which exception are you getting?

Comment: it looks fine here `http://jsfiddle.net/CUa2a/` If however you mean the commented out code `$( height).height()` you need to replace height with window `$( window).height()`

Comment: Looks fine here as well: [http://jsfiddle.net/spaceagecrystal/q6vhc/](http://jsfiddle.net/spaceagecrystal/q6vhc/) If you're using js Fiddle, you may need to set it to onDomready in the dropdown.

Comment: It's the call to height() that is not working correctly. I realise about the `$( height ).height() being incorrect but that's another matter.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, you've commented out the relevant part. You're attempting to use the `height` variable within the `window.load` function, but that variable doesn't exist in that scope, nor would your second `window.load` event have been evaluated yet.

There's no sense in doubling up your code here. Move all your `window.load` code here into a single function. jQuery isn't limited to use within its own event listeners, as you seem to have done here.

Comment: the exception is thrown when I try `var height = $( window ).height()`. It's the call to height() throwing the exception not the attempted use of height variable